# Reinforcement algorithm for binary classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, reinforcement-learning

I am new to machine learning, but I've read a lot about Reinforcement Learning in the past 2 days. I have an application that fetches a list of projects (e.g. from Upwork). There is a moderator that manually accepts or rejects a project (based on some parameters explained below). If a project is accepted, I want to send a project proposal and if it is rejected, I'll ignore it. **I am looking to replace that moderator with AI (among other reasons) so I want to know which Reinforcement Algorithm should I use for this.**

Parameters:
Some of the parameters that should decide whether the agent accepts or rejects the project are listed below. Assuming I only want to accept projects related to web development (specifically backend/server-side) here is how the parameters should influence the agent.

- *Sector*: If the project is in related to IT sector it should have more chances of being accepted.
- *Category*: If the project is in the Web Development category it should have more chances of being accepted.
- *Employer Rating*: Employers having a rating of over 4 (out of 5) should have more chances of being accepted.

I thought Q-Learning or SARSA would be able to help me out but most of the examples that I saw were related to Cliff Walking problem where the states are dependent on each other which is not applicable in my case since each project is different from the previous one.

Note: I want the agent to be self-learning so that if in the future I start rewarding it for front-end projects too, it should learn that behavior. Therefore, suggesting a "pure" supervised learning algorithm won't work.

Edit 1: I would like to add that I have data (sector, category, title, employer rating etc.) of 3000 projects along with whether that project was accepted or rejected by my moderator.

Comment: I don't think you have a RL problem here. You *might* have a contextual bandit - but even that is not clear. Is there a meaningful reward for getting the categorisation right, or a penalty for getting it wrong? If not, and you just want an *accurate* system based on your moderator's assignment, then this is neither RL nor contextual bandit, but most likely a supervised learning problem. Your "self-learning" requirement is usually called online learning, and you can get online supervised learning algorithms.

Comment: @NeilSlater thank you for your input. Yes, there will be a reward for categorizing correctly and a negative reward otherwise.

Comment: @NeilSlater the reason for keeping it self-learning (without supervised learning) is because in the future I might want to accept front-end projects in addition to the back-end projects. To make this happen, I will give negative rewards if the agent rejects front-end projects. I read about Contextual Bandit (CB) but I'm not sure whether the potential projects should be the _state_ or _bandit_. Any idea on how CB can be applied for my case?

Comment: I don't think this is a CB either. I think you need to get back to basics and state your problem, as opposed to pick an approach and try to make it fit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to frame it as traditional binary classification to start with. The problem is batched data with target labels and tabular features.

Later, reframe it as a reinforcement learning problem.